# add a sleep in my loop

Tags: java

I can't get it to sleep, I want it to pause for a second before continuing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
        //supply your own path instead of using this one 
        String path = "\\image.JPG";  
        for(;;)
            SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(     
                new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER),    
                new UINT_PTR(0),      
                path,          
                new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));
        }
```

When i try to add Thread.sleep(1000); it gives me an error, unreachable code.

Comment: Where are you adding it?

Comment: Where are you adding the Thread.sleep() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this... adding the sleep method inside the for loop.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
        //supply your own path instead of using this one 
        String path = "\\image.JPG"; 

        for(;;){

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(     
                    new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER),    
                    new UINT_PTR(0),      
                    path,          
                    new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }


          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're adding the `sleep()` to the inside of the for loop, not outside.

You also need to catch the potential `InterruptedException`.

```
for(;;)
    SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(     
        new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER),    
        new UINT_PTR(0),      
        path,          
        new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000l);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
```